# How can I open/view this set of ArcGIS files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-conversion, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have five files:

NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.img
NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.img.aux.xml
NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.img.vat.dbf
NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.img.xml
NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.lyr
NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.rrd

I understand that these files make up a raster layer. I want to be able to view them in ArcGIS. However when I try using the web developer portal, it seems to want a shapefile. This is not a shapefile. Perhaps I have to be using ArcGIS Desktop?

I can't find any documentation on this specific set of files online.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Web Developer Portal, however for the raster layer you'd use either the `.lyr` or the `.img` file.  The `.lyr` is the Layer file which stores information about how to display the raster, and the `.img` file is the raster image itself.  The rest are complimentary files to the `.img`.

Comment: So theoretically, all of the information is all in that NCC_Aerial_SanFrancisco_1999_2010_KelpPersistence.img  file and then the .lyr file tells it where it should go on the map?

Comment: Perhaps the layer is broken. The .IMG should be an ERDAS Imagine IMG file, however there may be an .IGE file missing if it's a particularly large file. ArcGis Desktop should be able to open/read the IMG file; if you don't have this available then QGIS should be able to open it... if the IMG can't be read by either QGIS or ArcGis Desktop it's broken and you should seek resupply. The .LYR file contains information about *how* to display the image, what colours, stretch, classification and transparency etc..

Comment: You need to use Desktop, meaning ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro. You can open either the .img or the .lyr. The LYR is just a pointer to the raster file but has defined a way to symbolize/render it. You'd need to have published the raster as an image service or map service to view it with "web / portal"

Answer (score 1):

I should have just made an answer instead of a comment --

The file(s) you reference in your question make up an Imagine (raster). To view a raster in the "Web", meaning through a web application, you need to have published it as a service. You can publish a raster inside either MapService or an ImageService.

You cannot upload a raster to ArcGIS.com / Portal and have it displayed.

Alternatively if you simply want to work with, inspect the raster without any web components, you can use ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap. These are desktop applications that can read the raster.

Your raster comes with a .lyr (layer file). This file defines how to draw and symbolize the raster inside the Desktop applications. When opening the raster, point to this file (instead of the .img) to see how the person who created these files suggests drawing it.